# Converting int list to vector list

Tags: data-science-model, classifier

I want to train a text classifier using OnevsRestClassifier, but have problem getting a propper y. Currenly my y is a list of int, but I need it as a list of vectors.

My y:

```
y = [0,2,5,1,3,2,4,2]
```

What I want:

```
y=[[1,0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,1,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,1],
   [0,1,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,1,0,0],
   [0,0,1,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,1,0],
   [0,0,1,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Try searching for OneHot... Search in Sklearn As a side note, indexing in Python is from 0 so you probably have an extra column

Comment: Hi @Max! What is the language you want to use? Could you provide the outome of your research? There is no evidence, that you search it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use the get_dummies function from pandas.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.get_dummies([0,2,5,1,3,2,4,2]).values.tolist()
```

gives us the the following:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```